# How to check the data in the smart fields?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Below is the example I tried from my side but don't know how to check in the smart fields. Please take a look and provide an impeccable answer.

```
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_part_obj           AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_product_family_obj AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_shipping_info_obj  AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE dt_sched_date_from    AS DATE       NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE dt_sched_date_to      AS DATE       NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_word_obj           AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_seq_no             AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_intseq             AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_ordno_obj          AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE de_wolv_obj           AS DECIMAL    NO-UNDO. 
  DEFINE VARIABLE cPipeLinekey          AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE cPipeLinestatus       AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.


  ASSIGN de_part_obj           = DYNAMIC-FUNCTION('getKeyFieldValue'  IN h_dynlookup_part)

         cPipeLinekey          = fi_PipeLineKey:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}
         cPipeLinestatus       = fi_PipeLineStatus:SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}
         de_word_obj           = DYNAMIC-FUNCTION('getKeyFieldValue'  IN h_dynlookup_worderid)
         de_seq_no             = DYNAMIC-FUNCTION('getKeyFieldValue'  IN h_dynlookup_Seq)     
.
.
.
.
/* AND SO ON*/
 IF de_part_obj <> 0.0 AND de_product_family_obj = 0.0 AND de_shipping_info_obj = 0.0 AND de_word_obj = 0.0 AND de_seq_no = 0.0 AND de_intseq = 0.0 AND de_ordno_obj = 0.0
               AND de_wolv_obj = 0.0 AND cPipeLinekey = ? AND cPipeLinestatus = ? THEN TRUE /* Allow only de_part_obj <> 0.0 */
.
.
.

/* up to cPipeLinestatus <> ? */
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile so I'll try to get you a standard snippet you can place wherever you'd like. This will respond to fill-ins in your frame (change from {&frame-name} if it's not the case, or make it {&frame-name} if you'd prefer. It shows a message telling you if nothing has been entered in it.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hField AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

  ASSIGN hField = FRAME {&frame-name}:FIRST-CHILD:FIRST-CHILD.

  DO WHILE VALID-HANDLE(hField) :

     IF hField:TYPE = "Fill-in" THEN

        MESSAGE "Name: " hField:NAME

                SKIP "Type: " hField:TYPE

                SKIP "Is it empty? "  hField:SCREEN-VALUE = ""

         VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.

     ASSIGN hField = hField:NEXT-SIBLING.

  END.
```

Comment: Its work for fill in type but what about the type for smart field?

Comment: Just in case, message the widget TYPE property to see what it's called, then adjust.

Comment: Yes I found that type is FRAME for smart field but cannot use SCREEN-VALUE attribute to check whether the field is having value or not. So i could use dynamic function for each field again one by one as you can see in the code section. Could you please help this case?

Comment: The code I posted should go in the master. You're probably seeing Frame because you're checking from the main window. If you place it in the master, the check will trigger automatically for every window that uses that smart data field.